# Binding nested class list from View to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I need to bind a List inside a nested class to my ActionMethod.

Now, on calling the ActionMethod (look below), ActionItemList is *null*

Unfortunately i can't move the List into the main Model.

This is my main Model:

```
public class StateViewModel
{
    public EmergencyOperationActionListModel ActionListModel { get; set; }
    public EmergencyInfoModel InfoModel
    public EmergencyInfoCauseListModel CauseListModel { get; set; }
}
```

and the nested one:

```
public class EmergencyInterventiActionListModel
{
    public string Firefighters { get; set; }
    public string ExternalAssistance { get; set; }
    public string PlacesDescription { get; set; }
    public List<ActionItemModel> ActionItemList { get; set; }
}
```

The view:

```
        @model Emergencies.Models.StatoViewModel


        //...code code code

        @using (Html.BeginForm("EditOps", "Operations")
        {

            <table class="table table-responsive table-hover" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
                <thead class="headOperations">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            CompanyName
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Workers
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Due Date
                        </td>
                        <td>
                           Start Date
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            End Date
                        </td>
                        <td>
                           Action
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                @if (Model.ActionListModel != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < Model.ActionListModel.ActionItemList.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.ActionListModel.ActionItemList[i].Id)

                                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ActionListModel.ActionItemList[i].CompanyName, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "companyEdit_" + Model.ActionListModel.ActionItemList[i].Id, @class = "editBoxForInterventi" } })
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ActionListModel.ActionItemList[i].NumberOfWorkers, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "workersEdit_" + Model.ActionListModel.ActionItemList[i].Id, style = "width:40px", @class = "editBoxForInterventi" } })
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="input-group date" id="duedateCalendar_@Model.ActionListModel.ActionItemList[i].Id">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ActionListModel.ActionItemList[i].DueDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { onclick = "CalendarDue('" + Model.ActionListModel.ActionItemList[i].Id + "')", id = "duedateEdit_" + Model.ActionListModel.ActionItemList[i].Id, @class = "editBoxForInterventi form-control dueDateCalendar", @readonly = "readonly" } })
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="input-group date" id="starttimeCalendar_@Model.ActionListModel.ActionItemList[i].Id">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ActionListModel.ActionItemList[i].StartTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "starttimeEdit_" + Model.ActionListModel.ActionItemList[i].Id, @class = "editBoxForInterventi  form-control starttimeCalendar", @readonly = "readonly" } })
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="input-group date" id="endtimeCalendar_@Model.ActionListModel.ActionItemList[i].Id">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ActionListModel.ActionItemList[i].EndTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "endtimeEdit_" + Model.ActionListModel.ActionItemList[i].Id, @class = "editBoxForInterventi  form-control endtimeCalendar", @readonly = "readonly" } })
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
            </table>
            <button type="submit" class="submit-with-icon btn btn-flussi-add" name="doButton" value="save">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
            </button>
        }

        //code code code...
```

And finally the controller:

```
  public ActionResult EditOps( List<ActionItemModel> ActionItemList )
{
    //code
}
```

Comment: Your form should be bound to the model itself. Change the type to StateViewModel in EditOps.

Comment: Forget to mention: i have (and use) other properties in StateViewModel, so i can't change it.

Comment: I didn't mean change the model... Change the signature of your EditOps method! Your view is bound to the model as per the @model directive at the top of the page. This is what the form data will be serialized into when posted! i.e.   EditOps( StateViewModel modelPosted )

Comment: Thanks @Wheels73. Following your advice i changed the signature from List<ActionItemModel> ActionItemList to EmergencyOperationActionListModel ActionListModel, and now it works. Ofc the names must match.

Comment: You're welcome... I'll post it as an answer for you then. Cheers

Comment: if you'd be so kind to upvote :)  I wouldn't normally ask but you can get down voted very quickly on this site.. so need to take any rep going! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your EditOps method signature to have the below.

```
public ActionResult EditOps(StateViewModel modelPosted)
{
    //access modelPosted here.
}
```

The whole model is serialized as per the @model directive in your view.